# Contact form plugin only sending the content of the textarea?

Tags: plugin-contactform

I'm working in a form with five fields, but I'm only receiving the content in the comments field; I'm not getting anything from the other four, please check my code
below.

```
<div class="form-container">
    <h3 class="aside-form__title">{{ block.contactFormHeadline }}</h3>
    {% macro errorList(errors) %}
    {% if message is defined %}
        {% if errors %}
            {% for error in errors %}
                <small class="error">{{ error }}</small>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endmacro %}
    {% from _self import errorList %}
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {{ getCsrfInput() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contactForm/sendMessage">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="fromName" type="text" name="fromName" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.fromName }}{% endif %}" placeholder="Full Name">
            {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromName')) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" name="fromEmail" id="from-email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.fromEmail }}{% endif %}">
            {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromEmail')) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="message[Company]" id="company" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name" value="">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="phone" type="text" name="message[Phone]" value="" Placeholder="Phone Number">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea rows="3" cols="30" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Comments">{% if message is defined %}{{ message.message }}{% endif %}</textarea>
            {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('message')) }}
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="Btn mini-form" value="Submit">
         </div>
        <input type="text" name="sales" id="sales" class="hidden">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using multiple fields, you'll need to use `message[body]` for the main message field's `name` attribute. Passing just `message` as the name for your main text field will clobber your other custom fields that precede it, as will custom fields, if they appear after it.

I think the only fix you'll need in this case is to the “Comments” `textarea`:

```
<textarea name="message[body]">Your initial text</textarea>
```